# Using the Data Set Stage to read the file as a single record

Tags: datastage

I have an DataStage Dat Set file and the Data Set has 120 columns. I’m trying to use the Data Set Stage to read records in one field. Is this possible? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. A Data Set is constrained by the metadata sitting in its descriptor file.  You could, of course, use a Column Export stage immediately following the Data Set stage, to convert the 120 columns into a single delimited string.

Comment: Thanks Ray.  More details, apologies.  I want this to be a generic job.  So using the Column Export after the Data Set Stage would get me there, however I would have to create a new job for every new Data Set that come my way.  True?

Comment: Your original question specified "the" Data Set.  Unless you can do something funky with column renaming or Runtime Column Propagation in an intermediate Copy stage, then I suspect you're up for non-generic jobs.  This is sometimes the best solution - each is self-documenting.

Comment: Thanks Ray And apologies for not being more specific.  I had not thought of RCP and will give that a try.  You mentioned "column renaming".  I have never heard or seen that.  would you elaborate?  Thanks.